# images in Elm 0.17

Tags: elm

I am trying a test example with a single image:

```
import Html exposing (Html)
import Graphics.Element
main = image 960 500 "starry-night.jpg"
```

I am trying this out with elm-reactor and this simple result doesn't compile:

```
I cannot find module 'Graphics.Element'.

Module 'Main' is trying to import it.

Potential problems could be:
  * Misspelled the module name
  * Need to add a source directory or new dependency to elm-package.json
```

I tried importing the necessary grahics package, [`evancz/elm-graphics`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-graphics/1.0.0)

```
john@me:~/Documents/Elm$ cat elm-package.json

{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "summary": "helpful summary of your project, less than 80 characters",
    "repository": "https://github.com/user/project.git",
    "license": "BSD3",
    "source-directories": [
        "."
    ],
    "exposed-modules": [],
    "dependencies": {
        "elm-lang/core": "4.0.1 <= v < 5.0.0",
        "elm-lang/html": "1.0.0 <= v < 2.0.0",
        "elm-lang/svg": "1.0.0 <= v < 2.0.0",
        "evancz/elm-graphics": "1.0.0 <= v < 2.0.0"
    },
    "elm-version": "0.17.0 <= v < 0.18.0"
}
```

---

I came up with:

```
import Html exposing (Html)
import Element exposing (image, toHtml)
main = toHtml ( image 960 500 "starry-night.jpg" )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the module is `Element`, not `Graphics.Element`, so that's why the compiler cannot find it.

Moreover, the `image` function returns an `Element`, while the `main` function desires something of the `Html` type.

A running version of your program could be something like

```elm
import Element exposing (..)

main =
    toHtml (image 960 500 "starry-night.jpg")
```